# Where to put list's at in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Where do you put extra list's at in android studio?

I am currently using a list in order to read from (it is a .txt file) but i need to know where the appropriate place is to put it?

The list contains 600+ lines of text and don't want to have to retype it all into the strings.xml.

Any help would be great, sorry if this question has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add it to /res/raw or to /assets.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!